# What is the meaning of "Director's Cut" in the context of comics?

Tags: terminology, comics

I have noticed that a few comic titles are also referred to as *Director's Cut* like DC's *Final Crisis 1: Director's Cut*. I know what a Director's Cut is in the context of film, as [discussed here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1614/directors-cut-editors-cut-theatrical-cut-what-do-these-mean) on our sister site.

But what is the meaning of *Director's Cut* in the context of comics?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does apply to comics, although comics really have no direct correlation to a film director.

The term is applied to any comic that is a reprint of any particular issue with added commentary by the writer or editor, script pages or production related artwork.

Quote from [Comicvine](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/directors-cut/4015-56076/):

> "Director's Cut comics are special release issues with added content that often includes: writer's commentary, editorials, background information and additional artwork."